# How to merge json array with same values in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have two array and i want to merge the data with the same value of

`"calleridnum":"0090000163",`
`"uid":"0090000163",`

this is my first array:

```
[
{
"_id":"55d44fe38879f12e6431c23c",
"event":"ConfbridgeJoin",
"channel":"SIP/peer_voip301confbridge-00000145",
"uniqueid":"1439977429.777",
"conference":"0090000167",
"calleridnum":"0090000163",
"calleridname":"0090000163",
"__v":0,
"sipSetting":{
"accountcode":"",
"accountcode_naisen":"202",
"extentype":0,
"extenrealname":"",
"name":"0090000163",
"secret":"Myojyo42f!",
"username":"0090000163",
"context":"innercall_xdigit",
"gid":101,
"cid":"0090000007"
}
}
]
```

This is my second array

```
[
{
"id":8,
"uid":"0090000163",
"cid":"0090000007",
"extension":"202",
"secret":"Myojyo42f!",
"leader":true,
"simultaneous":false,
"confbridge_id":6,
"created_at":"2015-08-18 09:22:20",
"updated_at":"2015-08-18 09:22:20"
},
{
"id":15,
"uid":"0090000164",
"cid":"0090000007",
"extension":"203",
"secret":"Myojyo42f!",
"leader":false,
"simultaneous":false,
"confbridge_id":6,
"created_at":"2015-08-19 01:26:30",
"updated_at":"2015-08-19 01:26:30"
}
]
```

i want to merge the object with the same value of 0090000163

i want to get if calleridnum == uid

i want to get this output

```js
"_id":"55d44fe38879f12e6431c23c",
    "event":"ConfbridgeJoin",
    "channel":"SIP/peer_voip301confbridge-00000145",
    "uniqueid":"1439977429.777",
    "conference":"0090000167",
    "calleridnum":"0090000163",
    "calleridname":"0090000163",
    "__v":0,
    "sipSetting":{
    "accountcode":"",
    "accountcode_naisen":"202",
    "extentype":0,
    "extenrealname":"",
    "name":"0090000163",
    "secret":"Myojyo42f!",
    "username":"0090000163",
    "context":"innercall_xdigit",
    "gid":101,
    "cid":"0090000007"
    "id":8,
    "uid":"0090000163",
    "cid":"0090000007",
    "extension":"202",
    "secret":"Myojyo42f!",
    "leader":true,
    "simultaneous":false,
    "confbridge_id":6,
    "created_at":"2015-08-18 09:22:20",
    "updated_at":"2015-08-18 09:22:20"
```

i do it in php . but i dont have much knowledge in javascript

this is my code in php

```
// $apiResults['participants'] == first array
// $apiResults['conference_participants'] == second array


$conf_participants = array();
      foreach($apiResults['participants'] as $participant)
      {
       foreach($apiResults['conference_participants'] as $conference_participant)
         {
    if($participant['calleridnum'] == $conference_participant['uid'])
        {

           $conf_participants['uniqueid'] = $participant['uniqueid'];
           $conf_participants['event'] = $participant['event'];
           $conf_participants['channel'] = $participant['channel'];
           $conf_participants['uid'] = $conference_participant['uid'];



       }
       }
      }
```

Comment: Do loop, check `if (calleridnum == uid)`, if true - `$.extend(array1, array2);`

Comment: No I want to know, what have you done still now ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lets say you have two arrays of objects `arr1` and `arr2` You need to loop through both, compare the value `calleridnum` from `arr1` and `uid`from `arr2` if they are same then merge the object `in arr1`.

```
for(var i in arr1){
for (var j in arr2)
   if (arr2[j].uid == arr1[i].calleridnum ) {
    $.extend(arr1[i], arr2[j]);
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: `arr1[i].merge` is not an existing function. Also, why didn't you just edit your other answer? Don't get me wrong, when you fix the merge function, this is the right answer.

Comment: .merge() is a jquery function

Comment: Yes, but it's not a function on a array or object. (`$.merge(a, b)`)

Comment: used to merge properties of two objects!

Comment: I know the function, but you're [calling it incorrectly.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/)

Comment: Please can you edit the answer and write the merge functionality there??

Comment: thanks a lot! but as far as i know this merge function is used to merge arrays can it be used for objects?

Comment: Oh, good point, for objects, you'll need to use [`extend`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)